# Deploying Django Channels to Elastic Beanstalk Python3.4 environment

Tags: django, python-3.x, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, supervisord, django-channels

I have spent the past few days implementing Channels into my Django app in order to use Channel's websocket support.  My Django project is written in Python 3.4 and I am using `Daphne` and Channel's `redis` backend.

I have been able to get everything functioning locally by wrapping Supervisord in a Python2 virtualenv and using it to run scripts that start Daphne/Redis/workers inside a Python3 virtualenv, but have had no success deploying to our Elastic Beanstalk (Python 3.4) environment.

Is there any way to set up my EB deployment configs to run Supervisor in a Python2 virtualenv, like I can locally?  If not, how can I go about getting Daphne, redis, and my workers up and running on EB deploy?  I am willing to switch process managers if necessary, but have found Supervisor's syntax to be easier to understand/implement than Circus, and am not aware of any other viable alternatives.

With this configuration, I am able to successfully deploy to my EB environment and ssh into it, but Supervisor fails to start every process, and if I try to start Supervisor manually to check on the processes `supervisorctl status` gives me `FATAL "Exited too quickly (process log may have details)` for everything I try to initialize.  The logs are empty.

Channels backend config:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer",
        "ROUTING": "<app>.routing.channel_routing",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [
                os.environ.get('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')
            ],
        },
    },
}
```

asgi.py:

```
import os
from channels.asgi import get_channel_layer

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "<app>.settings")

channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
```

supervisor conf (rest of the conf file was left default):

```
[program:Redis]
environment=PATH="/opt/python/run/venv/bin"
command=sh /opt/python/current/app/<app>/start_redis.sh
directory=/opt/python/current/app
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/tmp/redis.out.log

[program:Daphne]
environment=PATH="/opt/python/run/venv/bin"
command=sh /opt/python/current/app/<app>/start_daphne.sh
directory=/opt/python/current/app
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/tmp/daphne.out.log

[program:Worker]
environment=PATH="/opt/python/run/venv/bin"
command=sh /opt/python/current/app/<app>/start_worker.sh
directory=/opt/python/current/app
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
numprocs=4
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/tmp/workers.out.log
```

.ebextensions/channels.config:

```
container_commands:
  01_start_supervisord:
    command: "sh /supervisord/start_supervisor.sh"
```

start_supervisor.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 /tmp/senv
source /tmp/senv/bin/activate
sudo pip install supervisor
sudo /usr/local/bin/supervisord -c 
/opt/python/current/app/<app>/supervisord.conf
supervisorctl -c /opt/python/current/app/<app>/supervisord.conf status
```

start_redis:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sudo wget http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-3.2.8.tar.gz
sudo tar xzf redis-3.2.8.tar.gz
cd redis-3.2.8
sudo make
source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate
sudo src/redis-server
```

start_daphne:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate
/opt/python/run/venv/bin/daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 5000 <app>.asgi:channel_layer
```

start_worker:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate
python manage.py runworker
```

I was loosely following [this guide](https://blog.mangoforbreakfast.com/2017/02/13/django-channels-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk-using-an-alb/) but since it was written for a python2 EB environment it is really only good for the ALB setup and base supervisor configuration.

Thank you guys for reading this, and please let me know if I can provide anything else by way of code/output etc.

Comment: As a heads up to anyone looking into doing this, be aware that in an autoscaling EB environment there is a chance that an established websocket will not receive a sigkill or other signal upon an EC2 instance dying/being spun down.  This led to a lot of headaches for our frontend due to websocket connections suddenly not responding while remaining open.  I've since switched off the project and can't offer a solution, but wanted to point it out to maybe save someone some pain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So thanks to the logging advice from Berlin's answer, and an virtual environment tweak suggested by the AWS support team (I forwarded this question along to them), I was finally able to get this to work.

First off, I ended up completely removing `Redis` from Supervisor, and instead chose to run an ElastiCache Redis instance which I then connected to my EB instance.  I don't think this is the only way to handle this, but it was the best route for my implementation.

I then changed from using the pre-existing `start_supervisor.sh` script and instead added a command to `channels.config` ebextension to create the script and add it to EB's postdeployment operations.  This was necessary because `.ebextension` config files are run during deployment, but do not live past environment creation (this may not be entirely correct, but for the sake of this solution that is how I think of them), so even though my script was mostly correct the Supervisor process it started up would just die as soon as deployment was done.

so my `.ebextensions/channels.config` is now:

```
container_commands:
  01_create_post_dir:
    command: "mkdir /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post"
    ignoreErrors: true
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/start_supervisor.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 /tmp/senv
      source /tmp/senv/bin/activate && source /opt/python/current/env
      python --version > /tmp/version_check.txt
      sudo pip install supervisor
      /usr/local/bin/supervisord -c /opt/python/current/app/<app>/supervisord.conf
      supervisorctl -c /opt/python/current/app/<app>/supervisord.conf status
```

This alone was enough to get Supervisor running on EB deployment, but I had to make some more changes to get Daphne and my Django workers to stay alive:

start_daphne.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && source /opt/python/current/env
/opt/python/run/venv/bin/daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 5000 <app>.asgi:channel_layer
```

start_worker.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && source /opt/python/current/env
python manage.py runworker
```

Adding `&& source /opt/python/current/env` to the virtualenv activation command was suggested to me by AWS support, as env variables are not pulled into virtualenvs automatically, which was causing Daphne and workers to die on creation due to Import Errors.

I also made some changes to my `supervisord.conf` file:

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/tmp/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)

[supervisord]
logfile=/tmp/supervisord.log ; supervisord log file
loglevel=error ; info, debug, warn, trace
logfile_maxbytes=50MB        ; (max main logfile bytes b4 rotation;default 50MB)
logfile_backups=10           ; (num of main logfile rotation backups;default 10)
pidfile=/tmp/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
nodaemon=false               ; (start in foreground if true;default false)
minfds=1024                  ; (min. avail startup file descriptors;default 1024)
minprocs=200                 ; (min. avail process descriptors;default 200)

; the below section must remain in the config file for RPC
; (supervisorctl/web interface) to work, additional interfaces may be
; added by defining them in separate rpcinterface: sections
[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket

[program:Daphne]
environment=PATH="/opt/python/run/venv/bin"
command=sh /opt/python/current/app/<app>/start_daphne.sh --log-file /tmp/start_daphne.log
directory=/opt/python/current/app
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/tmp/daphne.out.log
stderr_logfile=/tmp/daphne.err.log

[program:Worker]
environment=PATH="/opt/python/run/venv/bin"
command=sh /opt/python/current/app/<app>/start_worker.sh --log-file /tmp/start_worker.log
directory=/opt/python/current/app
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
numprocs=4
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/tmp/workers.out.log
stderr_logfile=/tmp/workers.err.log
```

Comment: how do you set the redis host endpoint address in settings.py? I tried to grab the endpoint address using GetAtt, put it into env, and let django grab it. but it doesn't work.

Comment: if you can kindly share your ebextension config file(s) :)

Comment: @MarshallX for the redis host endpoint I found my Redis server's `primary endpoint` through AWS console (under ElastiCache), and set that as an environment variable that I get in `settings.py`.  All relevant config files are already included above.

Comment: I ended up the same approach too. wondering if I can grab the endpoint url from env.

Answer (score 2):

You said logs are empty, so hard to debug, make sure to have the log line on the main supervisor config file `/etc/supervisord.conf`, see what the errors and share them.

```
[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisord/supervisord.log ; supervisord log file
loglevel=error ; info, debug, warn, trace
```

And to each of your program on your supervisor conf file add a log error and see what is the errors and share them.

```
command=sh /opt/python/current/app/<app>/start_redis.sh --log-file /path/to/your/logs/start_redis.log
stdout_logfile=/tmp/redis.out.log
stderr_logfile=/tmp/redis.err.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a long and detailed google doc on how to do this linking to it here

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1naZsjO05Pa6uB9D-26eCeUVROZhz_MKkL8GI2knGLeo/edit?usp=sharing

And for any moderators, the reason I'm not typing it all in here is that the guide is long and with a lot of images. Figured it's worth sharing as it will help someone

Comment: @ Dr Manhattan, thanks for the  great write up in the linked google doc, Can you kindly say something about redis server/redis in production e.g ELASTICACHE in the Ec2.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: say something like what @ray lol, You need to be a lot more specific. what issues are you facing with redis in production ?

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the belated response.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the belated response.  I got the redis up after some research. Here's my concern, on my local machine, I have a working endpoint like this from the browser JavaScript client::  const client  = new W3WebSocket(`ws://localhost:8000/ws/chat/`). That's how the connection is defined on the client. I was wondering would I have to remove the "ws" from the URL and change it to http/https in an elasticbeanstalk . I.e  const client  = new W3WebSocket(`http://localhost:8000/ws/chat/`). Thanks and hope to hear from you.

Comment: No. The wss protocol establishes a WebSocket over an encrypted TLS connection, while the ws protocol uses an unencrypted connection. Read this for more clarity:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46557485/difference-between-ws-and-wss