# Difference between ws and wss?

Tags: websocket, java-websocket

What is the procedure to change ws into wss?

Whether wss is make upgrade over normal HTTP or wss works only HTTPS?

```
webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:port/Esv/ocp");
```

works fine, when I changed ws to wss

```
webSocket = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:port/Esv/ocp");
```

it shows this error:

> Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Answer (score 142, accepted):

## Short version

**To SSL or not SSL**

You may have a [SSL certificate issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29996698/4906586). The connection point rule can be [summarized as](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34554243/4906586):

- **`wss`** connects on **`https only`**
- **`ws`** connects on **`http`**

**and** vice-versa:

- **`https`** accepts **`wss only`**
- **`http`** accepts **`ws only`**

**Errors**

Following situations will lead you to an error (tests done under Firefox):

- If you want to connect a `wss` connection to a `http` endpoint. In my tests, I had an

  > InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable
- If you want to connect a `ws` connection to a `https` endpoint, you'll have the error

  > SecurityError: The operation is insecure.

## Formal answer

The bible of websocket is **[RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455)**. In section [**4.1.5**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#page-17):

> If */secure/* is true, the client MUST perform a TLS handshake over the connection after opening the connection and before sending the handshake data [RFC2818].  If this fails (e.g., the server's certificate could not be verified), then the client MUST *Fail the WebSocket Connection* and abort the connection.  Otherwise, all further communication on this channel MUST run through the encrypted tunnel [RFC5246].

The *secure* flag is defined by the URI. Section 3 defines what is *secure*

> The URI is called "secure" (and it is said that "the secure flag is set") if the scheme component matches "wss" case-insensitively.

---

## TL;DR

If you want to use `wss`:

- you must have SSL activated
- your endpoint point must be secured (`https://...`): "security downgrade" is not allowed

If you want to use `ws`:

- Make sure your endpoint does not have SSL enabled (`http://...`)

Comment: Thank you..And is really possible that wss works for http also?

Comment: Nope, websocket does not allow a "security" downgrade. I'll edit my answer to highlight that. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: @mahe I updated my answer following your feedback. Does it answer your question?

Comment: @mahe: The only way to connect WSS over HTTP is to use an intermediate WebSocket proxy that accepts WSS/HTTPS and forwards using WS/HTTP.

Comment: So it's NOT possible to initiate a WS with an HTTPS request? We have to use HTTP?

Comment: As far as I recall, you have the mirror the secured / non-secured connection.