# Action Cable Client implementation in React-native

Tags: react-native, actioncable

** **EDIT** **

The issue was, concerning iOS, the WebSocket URL. I had to change `ws://mywebsocket.io` to `wss://mywebsocket.io`. [See Here Why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46557485/difference-between-ws-and-wss)

I also had an issue with Android when working with my local server.
my WS url was `ws://localhost:3000/message`. It does work on iOS simulator but not on Android simulator (nor Expo).

Type `ifconfig | grep "inet" | grep -v 127.0.0.1` on your console
And get your public IP (such as `10.67.x.x`) and replace it in your WS url.

=> `ws://10.67.x.x:3000/message`.

It now works on iOS and Android.

---

I tried to implement `action cable` in my react-native project (built with CRNA).

I did it based on the [react-native-actioncable](https://github.com/cpunion/react-native-actioncable) and [react-actioncable-provider](https://github.com/cpunion/react-actioncable-provider) projects.

So i have a ConversationStack Navigator implementing :

```
class Conversations extends React.Component {
  static childContextTypes = {
    cable: PropTypes.object
  };

  state = {
    cable: null
  };

  getChildContext() {
    return {
      cable: this.state.cable
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const MY_URL = "ws://somethingwithmyurl" + "secret_parameter";

    this.setState({
      cable: RNActionCable.createConsumer(MY_URL)
    });
  }

  render() {
    // screenProps forces update of ConversationStack screens when   Context is set
    return <ConversationStack screenProps={this.state} />;
  }
}

export default Conversations;
```

My WebSocket URL is defined programmatically. It doesn't change anything at all, it just forces me to not use `ActionCableProvider` here and to pass my cable instance as context. It works the same. [No doubt](https://github.com/cpunion/react-actioncable-provider/issues/13)

Then. I just have an ActionCable instance which received and send message.

```
import { ActionCable } from "react-actioncable-provider";


class Conversation extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    cable: PropTypes.object
  };


this.state = {
  messages: []
};


  /**
   * onReceived()
   * Process the received message and append it to messages
   */
  onReceived = message => {
    ...
  };

  /**
   * onSend()
   * Perform "speak" when sending a Message
   */
  onSend = (messages = []) => {
   ...
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        {this.context.cable && (
          // Check cable is available
          <ActionCable
            ref="roomChannel"
            channel={{ channel: "MessageChanel" }}
            onReceived={this.onReceived}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

based on [TestRNActionCable](https://github.com/cpunion/TestRNActionCable)

It doesn't work on iOS.

If you have another `ActionCable` implementation for react-native, i would be more than glad to take a look at it.
 Otherwise, let me know if your implementation did work on both mobile and why.