# WebSocket connection to 'ws:/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

Tags: django, django-channels

I am using `Django-channels` to connect to the server, but it always show the error like this:

```
reconnectwebsockets.js WebSocket connection to 'ws:xxx' failed: 
Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200
```

Also, I am using `docker`, this may be a issue of docker container configuration?
Any ideas what could be possibly wrong?

Answer (score 0):

## Question details

Hello, did you try to use [`channels`](https://github.com/django/channels) library? It will give you same powerful as `Django-channels` one. [Here](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) you can find necessary documentation for it.

I recommend you use it because it is give you more flexibility then `Django-channels` one.

## Channels library

### Quick start

You can read how to work with it at [Tutorial](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/index.html).

### Errors and solutions

#### Unexpected response code: 200 (or other code XXX) (solved):

- Be sure you include your application and channels via `settings` (`mysite.settings`) and use `asgi` application:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'channels',
    'chat',
    ...
]
...
ASGI_APPLICATION = "mysite.asgi.application"
```

- Be sure you use channel layers (`mysite.settings`).

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer',
    },
}
```

> According [Documentation](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/channel_layers.html#in-memory-channel-layer) you should use database for production, but for local  environment you may use `channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer`.

- Be sure you run **`asgi`** server (not `wsgi`) because you need asynchronous behaviour. Also, for deployment you should use [`daphne`](https://github.com/django/daphne) instead of `gunicorn`. [`daphne`](https://github.com/django/daphne) is included in [`channels`](https://github.com/django/channels) library by default, so you don't need to install it manually.
  Basic run server will look like (Terminal):

```
daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p $PORT mysite.asgi:application
```

where `$PORT` is specific port (for UNIX system is 5000). (That format used for heroku application, you can change it manually).

#### Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR and same errors with using https connection (solved):

> [Difference between ws and wss?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46557485/difference-between-ws-and-wss)

You may think about to use your server via wss protocol:
replace `ws://...` with `wss://...` or use following template in your html (`chat/templates/chat/room.html`):

```
(window.location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'wss' : 'ws') + '://'
```

Hope this answer is useful for `channels` with `Django`.