# Spring boot : WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:9595/chat' failed

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket

I have created application with spring boot and it has spring security & added code of  websocket in spring boot application But I am not able to establish connection with websocket. I got an error when I'm trying to establish connection from front end.

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:9595/chat' failed
CLOSED: wss://localhost:9595/chat
```

Comment: try url "ws" instead of "wss" wss should be used when you have secure connection. more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46557485/difference-between-ws-and-wss
Also when asking question you should give here an example of code you are using. There is a lot of implementations of websockets out there

Comment: @Szprota21 I have using secured connection So preferred wss.

Comment: even if it's secured connection it's on localhost which isn't helping because is not resolvable ssl certificate. Anyway without any example here no one will be able to help you. You should post code for your ws client and ws server for it to be minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example